# pfsense routing table: link vs interface

Tags: pfsense, links, network-interface, routing-table

Here is my pfsense IPv4 outing table (netatst -r):

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
default            192.168.4.1        UGS         em0
127.0.0.1          link#4             UH          lo0
192.168.1.0/24     link#2             U           em1
192.168.1.1        link#2             UHS         lo0
192.168.4.0/22     link#1             U           em0
192.168.4.1        08:00:27:fa:40:cf  UHS         em0
192.168.4.48       link#1             UHS         lo0
```

How do I interpret the link#X vs the interface? The IP of pfsense is 192.168.1.1 (LAN) and 192.168.4.48 (WAN). Is the link a "lower level" concept than the interface? Why can the same link have different interfaces depending on the destination?